# Parse datetime with ISO format in Scala

Tags: java, scala, simpledateformat, iso8601

Which format I should use to parse a String date (using ISO 8601) in Scala?

> 2018-12-13T19:19:08.266120+00:00

I just try some patterns but no success. This code show me a near date as String, but when I try with a String above, with timezone info, I get error.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'SXXX").format(new Date())
```

Result:

> 2018-12-14T17:41:24.929-02:00

Error:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:
>   "2018-12-13T19:19:08.266120+00:00"   at
>   java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)   ... 29 elided

Comment: Don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. For one, it’s notoriously troublesome, secondly it cannot parse 6 decimals on the second (microseconds), it supports only milliseconds. Fortunately it’s also long outdated, supplanted by `DateTimeFormatter` of java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. I get `Thu Dec 13 20:23:34 CET 2018`. The result is clearly incorrect, so I *would* have preferred the exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DateTimeFormatter` [class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) includes a number of predefined formats, including a few ISO formats. Here's one that appears to work for your example `String`.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter._

val dts = "2018-12-13T19:19:08.266120+00:00"
LocalDateTime.parse(dts, ISO_DATE_TIME)
//res0: java.time.LocalDateTime = 2018-12-13T19:19:08.266120
```

Comment: Still better, use the one-arg `OffsetDateTime.parse(String)`. No need for an explicit formatter, and you will also pick up the offset from the string (in this case +00:00).

Comment: It works! Thank you so much @jwvh